# Eloquent Laravel - Coluna user_id

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent, value, set, default

Olá, estou aprendendo laravel e não achei isso em nenhum fórum. Tenho algumas tabelas que tem uma chave estrangeira chamada 'user_id', porém quando vou salvar um objeto no banco sempre tenho que preencher essa coluna. Tem como eu 'ensinar' o laravel que sempre que vou criar um objeto a coluna user id se refere à `auth()->user()->id`?

Eis como estou fazendo:

```
$data = $request->all();
$data['user_id'] = auth()->user()->id;
UmObjetoQualquer::create($data)
```

Comment: Não deu certo a resposta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precisa ser criado um observador onde no método antes de criar um novo registro (`creating`) pode configurar um valor para esse `model`, um exemplo minimo:

Criado um model dentro da pasta `App` com o nome de `Test`:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Test extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name','user_id'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
}
```

Crie dentro da pasta `App` uma outra pasta com o nome de `Observers` e dentro dessa pasta um `TestObserver.php` com o seguinte código:

```
<?php namespace App\Observers;

use App\Test;

class TestObserver 
{
    public function creating(Test $model)
    {
        $model->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    }   
}
```

e para que esse observe seja executado no momento antes de salvar os dados na base na pasta `app\Providers` abra o arquivo `AppServiceProvider` e dentro do método `boot` adicione a seguinte linha:

```
Test::observe(TestObserver::class);
```

Atenção: não esqueça de colocar os `uses`, exemplo completo do `AppServiceProvider.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Observers\TestObserver;
use App\Test;
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
        Test::observe(TestObserver::class);
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

com essas devidas configurações todas as vezes que tentar criar um novo registro para um determinado `model` configurado automaticamente o valor do usuário logado será passado para o `model` e logo após serão salvos com os outros dados que já foram passados.

Nota que além do método `creating` que refere-se ao modelo antes de salvar os dados existe outros como:

- retrieved
- creating
- created
- updating
- updated
- saving
- saved
- deleting
- deleted
- restoring
- restored

que podem ser configurados, mas, o exemplo dado é referente a sua pergunta.

<sub>***Referencia:***</sub>

- [Observers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#observers)
- [Laravel: Model Observers](https://bosnadev.com/2014/12/28/laravel-model-observers/)
- [Using Laravel Model Observers](https://tutsforweb.com/laravel-model-observers-tutorial/)
- [Model events and Observers in Laravel 5.0](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/model-events-and-observers-in-laravel-50)

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção, não é tão difícil. Eu leio a documentação mas a do Laravel eu não consigo entender tão fácil igual a do bootstrap, sou novo nisso. Obrigado (:

Comment: Não deixe de aceitar se for útil @JhonnyIzidoro

Comment: Funcionou (:...

Answer (score 0):

É só você colocar no model User o campo "user_id" nos fillables.

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use EntrustUserTrait;

    protected $fillable = [
        'id','name', 'email', 'password','user_id'
    ];


    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

}
```

Dessa forma você não irá precisar especificar para salvar, assim como os demais campos.

Comment: Vou testar, assim é bem simples, obrigado!