# Executar ação antes de salvar?

Tags: laravel-5, sql-insert

Estou recebendo os `requests` do formulário e colocando tudo de uma vez para salvar utilizando o `protected $fillable = ['nome', 'idade', 'cep', 'nr_casa'];` do **Laravel**

Estou recebendo assim:

```
public function save(Request $request)
{
   $user = new User( $request->all() );
   $user->save();
}
```

O `cep` digitado no `input` é assim: **69.084-120** e gostaria que antes de salvar ele formatasse para **69084120**.

Existe alguma função `beforeSave` no **Laravel** assim como o **Yii**?

Minha tabela está

```
nome varchar(100)
idade int
cep varchar(8)
nr_casa varchar(10)
```

Comment: Qual a versão do Laravel?

Comment: A versão do Laravel é 5.7

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Eloquent Laravel - Coluna user\_id](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/297038/eloquent-laravel-coluna-user-id)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim existe a parte de eventos que é constituída por uma classe que gera algum ou algumas modificações antes dos evento por exemplo de salvar, no seu exemplo de código pode ser utilizado um `creating` para que antes de criar esse registro tenha alguma modificação, ***exemplo***:

Crie uma classe na pasta `app\Observers` que vai representar essas alterações:

```php
class UserObserve 
{
    public function creating(User $user) // somente na hora da criação
    {
        $user->cep = str_replace(['.','-'],'',$user->cep);
    }
    // OU
    // talvez no seu caso o evento é saving porque
    // nesse caso é antes de salvar qualquer modificação
    public function saving(User $user)
    {
        $user->cep = str_replace(['.','-'],'',$user->cep);          
    }
}
```

***Observação:*** fiz dois métodos, você pode utilizar um o outro, um significa na criação desse registro (`creating`) e o outro todas as vezes antes de salvar (`saving`). Existe no caso ainda mais: `retrieved`, `creating`, `created`, `updating`, `updated`, `saving`, `saved`, `deleting`, `deleted`, `restoring` e `restored`.

No `AppServiceProvider` que está na pasta `app\Providers` adicione no método `boot` o seguinte trecho de código:

```php
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function boot()
    {
        User::observe(UserObserve::class);
    }

    public function register()
    {
    }
}
```

<sub>**Outro exemplo:**</sub>

- [Eloquent Laravel - Coluna user_id](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/297038/eloquent-laravel-coluna-user-id/297053#297053)

<sub>***Referencia:***</sub>

- [Observers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#observers)
- [Laravel: Model Observers](https://bosnadev.com/2014/12/28/laravel-model-observers/)
- [Using Laravel Model Observers](https://tutsforweb.com/laravel-model-observers-tutorial/)
- [Model events and Observers in Laravel 5.0](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/model-events-and-observers-in-laravel-50)

Comment: No caso, vou ter que criar primeiro a pasta Events, é isso ou posso usar o php artisan?

Comment: @adventistaam sim, olha o outro exemplo ta melhor explicado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/297038/eloquent-laravel-coluna-user-id/297053#297053

Comment: @adventistaam fiz alguns alterações ...

Comment: Tem que fazer todos os imports normais, é isso? Porque ainda nao funcionou

Comment: Sim claro todos os `imports` @adventistaam o que não funcionou o erro?

Comment: Como coloquei o limite do campo pra 08, ele continua colocando os pontos e traço

Answer (score 1):

O laravel já tem uma estrutura já prevista para isso nos models, são os mutators:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators
neste caso, você pode utilizar:

```
public function setCepAttribute($value) {
    $this->attributes['cep'] = str_replace(['.','-'],['',''],($value);
}
```

da mesma forma que pode também colocar os pontos e traços de volta ao buscar o valor criando a função

```
public function getCepAttribute($value) {
   return TRATAR O VALOR AQUI.
}
```

Comment: Isso dentro da model?

Comment: sim, basta criar as funções com o nome do atributo que quer modificar.

Comment: Deu problema na coluna nr_casa que é varchar